# Ubuntu14.04 Indigo-desktop-full install problem

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using Ubuntu14.04 LTS. I have successfully install ros-indigo-desktop, but to use the simulators and navigation feature, it seems I have to install the ros-indigo-deaktop-full.

So following the steps, I setup the sources.list and setup up the keys successfully. When I input the command "sudo apt-get update", two of the source failed, but I think these sources have nothing to do with the ros installation, however I'm not quite sure. So I put the info here:

```
Err: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
   404 Not Found
Err: http://ppa.lauchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
   404 Not Found

...

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/t-tujikawa/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/m

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/t-tujikawa/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/m

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used
```

I ignore the problem(because I think the source has nothing to do with ros) and continue. In the terminal I typed in "sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full" and get following errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then I typed in "sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-simulators" and get following errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-simulators : Depends: ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-pkgs but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then I typed in "sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-pkgs" and get following errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-pkgs : Depends: ros-indigo-gazebo-plugins but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: ros-indigo-gazebo-ros but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then I typed in "sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-gazebo-plugins" and get following errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-gazebo-plugins : Depends: gazebo2 but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-indigo-gazebo-ros but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I typed in "sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-gazebo-ros", I get following errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-gazebo-ros : Depends: gazebo2 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**So It seem that my problem comes from the failure when installing gazebo2**.
When I typed in "sudo apt-get install gazebo2", I get following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gazebo2 : Depends: libsdformat-dev (< 2.0.0) but 3.6.0-1~201512071 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I googled this "gazebo2 : Depends: libsdformat-dev (< 2.0.0) but 3.6.0-1~201512071 is to be installed" and get nothing involved to solve the problem.
By the way, when I typed in "apt-cache policy libsdfformat-dev", I get follows:

```
libsdformat-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  **Candidate: 3.6.0-1~201512071**
  Version table:
     3.6.0-1~201512071 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deb-rob/ros-trusty/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     1.4.11-1ubuntu0.1 0
        500 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     1.4.11-1osrf1 0
        500 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     1.4.11-1 0
        500 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

By the way, I have installed libsdformat1.( I install this because I googled other relevant but not exact same problem which suggests install libsdformat1, however it doesn't work for me )

I have been struck here for a very long time, can any one help me? I will really appreciate it very very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243034/ubuntu14.04-indigo-desktop-full-install-problem/) by [zinkcious](https://answers.ros.org/users/27887/zinkcious/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-09-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you've installed a different version of ROS from [https://launchpad.net/~deb-rob/+archive/ubuntu/ros-trusty](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeb-rob/+archive/ubuntu/ros-trusty) , and the packages from that repository are conflicting with the official ROS packages.

The obvious package that's conflicting is libsdformat, but given the size of that repository I suspect there are other conflicts too.

You'll need to remove the conflicting packages that you installed from that repository if you want to install the packages from the official repository; that will probably mean uninstalling the other version of ROS from that repository.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zinkcious](https://answers.ros.org/users/27887/zinkcious/) on 2016-09-03**:
How do you know I have installed a different version of ROS? I just followed the steps in http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu. At first I want to install desktop-full but get similar dependency errors, so I install desktop instead.When I get back to install desktop-full, I still get error

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-09-05**:
The information from `apt-cache policy libsdfformat-dev` shows that you have that PPA enabled, and that it's providing a conflicting version of libsdfformat-dev.

**Comment by [zinkcious](https://answers.ros.org/users/27887/zinkcious/) on 2016-09-08**:
Sorry, I just get to know what you mean. I don't know why there are two sources relevant from ros, when I check the directory in /opt/ros, there is only one folder "indigo" in the directory, so what you suggest now? should I uninstall the ros using "sudo apt-get purge ros-indigo-*" and reinstall?

**Comment by [zinkcious](https://answers.ros.org/users/27887/zinkcious/) on 2016-09-09**:
I install the specific version libsdformat-dev=1.4.11-1osrf1 using "sudo apt-get install libsdformat-dev=1.4.11-1osrf1" which is the dependency of the official ros, it tells that it depends "libsdformat1=1.4.11-1osrf1", so I install it too. After that, I install "ros-indigo-desktop-full" and success

**Comment by [zinkcious](https://answers.ros.org/users/27887/zinkcious/) on 2016-09-09**:
But I still don't know where the ppa([https://launchpad.net/~deb-rob/+archive/ubuntu/ros-trusty](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeb-rob/+archive/ubuntu/ros-trusty)) comes from, do you know why?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-09-09**:
That PPA is not part of the standard installation instructions, and it isn't a default with Ubuntu. It's there because you (or someone else with access to your computer) did something that put it there.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-09-09**:
The only guide I can find that documents adding that repository is https://wiki.debian.org/DebianScience/Robotics/ROS ; perhaps you followed that guide at some point in the past?

**Comment by [zinkcious](https://answers.ros.org/users/27887/zinkcious/) on 2016-09-26**:
I haven't follow this guide before. And I don't know where that ppa come from. Any way,  this problem is solved. But now I encounter a new problem now. The question address is "http://answers.ros.org/question/244237/rosrun-map_server-map_server-couldnt-find-executable/", can you help me out?